# QuickBlox, how to create 1:1 chat

Tags: android, quickblox

I've been bumping my head to the wall for hours now, I'm trying to make the simplest chat activity using QuickBlox, so far I've managed to create users and sign them in, the problem comes in when I call:

```
chat = QBChatService.getInstance().createChat();
```

It throws an Illegal state exception saying that I have to be logged in, I can't find anything on how createChat works so am wandering the dark here .. any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Soooo.. I got it to work, and am not telling you how :@ lol, all I had to do was to log in using:

```
QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser(..);
```

As simple as that !